# Get data from Xpath in a page - java

Tags: java, url, xpath

I need to get the data from the below link

"http://www.portaldatransparencia.gov.br/servidores/Servidor-DetalhaRemuneracao.asp?Op=1&IdServidor=1952541&bInformacaoFinanceira=True"

In below XPath I need this to run several times, just changing the number in the link, but I don't know how to return the data I need.

`"//*[@id="listagemConvenios"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]"`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic xpath as below:-

```
String dd;
for(int i = 1; i <= counti; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 1; i <= countj; ++i)
    {
       dd= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='listagemConvenios']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText()   ;
    }
}
```